# How to split intersected Labels in WFP C#.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I created this WFP application that generates Labels in certain locations in the Form to show a weekly planning based on settings from other form

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15KZq.png)

```
CustomLabel.Add(new Label()):
(CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Label).Location = new System.Drawing.Point(117,Y(LISTPLANS[MainForm.indexplan].Subjects.ElementAt<Subject(i).PSchedule.StartTime));
(CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Label).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(97,L(LISTPLANS[MainForm.indexplan].Subjects.ElementAt<Subject(i).PSchedule.StartTime,LISTPLANS[MainForm.indexplan].Subjects.ElementAt<Subject>(i).PSchedule.EndTime));
Controls.Add(CustomLabel[CustomLabel.Count - 1] as Control);
```

The size and the location of the Label is relative to the starting DateTime and ending DateTime and of course the Day:

```
public Int32 Y(DateTime StartTime)
{
    double onehour = 19.5;
    double minute = Math.Ceiling(StartTime.Minute / 15.0) / 4.0;
    switch (StartTime.Hour)
    {
        case 6:
            return (Int32)(94 + minute * onehour);
        case 7:
            return (Int32)(114 + minute * onehour);
        case 8:
            return (Int32)(135 + minute * onehour);
        case 9:
            return (Int32)(156 + minute * onehour);
        case 10:
            return (Int32)(177 + minute * onehour);
        case 11:
            return (Int32)(197 + minute * onehour);
        case 12:
            return (Int32)(219 + minute * onehour);
        case 13:
            return (Int32)(240 + minute * onehour);
        case 14:
            return (Int32)(260 + minute * onehour);
        case 15:
            return (Int32)(280 + minute * onehour);
        case 16:
            return (Int32)(302 + minute * onehour);
        case 17:
            return (Int32)(322 + minute * onehour);
        case 18:
            return (Int32)(344 + minute * onehour);
        case 19:
            return (Int32)(366 + minute * onehour);
        case 20:
            return (Int32)(388 + minute * onehour);
        case 21:
            return (Int32)(407 + minute * onehour);
        case 22:
            return (Int32)(428 + minute * onehour);
        case 23:
            return (Int32)(449 + minute * onehour);
        case 0:
            return (Int32)(470 + minute * onehour);
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
public Int32 L(DateTime StartTime, DateTime EndTime)
{
    return (Int32)(Y(EndTime) - Y(StartTime));
}
```

I figured this out, still the problem is if the user entered a time similar to a previously reserved time
the program will create a label on the old on ant it will hide it, same if the user set for example:
Subject1 : from 8:00 -> 11:00 - Saturday
Subject2 : from 10:00 -> 12:00 - Saturday
The generated two Labels will be intersected with each other.
I want a code that split these intersected Labels (the default width is 97) So that both will get a width 
of 48:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe0W2.png)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to first group the overlapping ones. Here's an example to illustrate the idea.

```
static IEnumerable<RectangleF> Layout(IEnumerable<(DateTime StartTime, DateTime EndTime)> source, SizeF area)
{
    static bool Overlaps(
        (DateTime StartTime, DateTime EndTime) a, 
        (DateTime StartTime, DateTime EndTime) b) =>
            a.StartTime <= b.StartTime && a.EndTime > b.StartTime ||
                a.StartTime <= b.EndTime && a.EndTime > b.EndTime;

    var set = new HashSet<(DateTime StartTime, DateTime EndTime)>();

    IEnumerable<RectangleF> results =
        from item in source
        let matches = source.Where(x => Overlaps(item, x) && set.Add(x)).ToList()
        from t in matches.Select((match, index) => (match, index))
        let y = t.match.StartTime.TimeOfDay.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * area.Height
        let height = (t.match.EndTime - t.match.StartTime).Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerDay * area.Height
        let x = t.index * 1f / matches.Count / area.Width
        let width = 1f / matches.Count * area.Width
        select new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more, I'm newbee

Comment: We'll need to group items that have overlapping time slots, so we can divide the available width amongst those that were matched. The code in this answer uses LINQ, which is just a little more concise to communicate the idea. The key takeaway here is where we find `matches` for every item in `source` - these must appear side-by-side each time, if there's more than 1.